# Transaction Data in Data Vault Model

Tags: data-warehouse, data-vault

I'm coding a data warehouse in data vault model.
But actually I'm not sure how to work with transaction data.
I have the following attributes

```
Service
Time(based on minutes)
Status
```

I have a hub table for Service, a hub table for Status and a hub table for Time, but it's not based on minutes.

The question is?
Are the transaction data link tables?
How would/do you design this?
thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctlly, below is the structure of the hubs :

`HUB Service (Hub_Service_HKEY >PK)`

`HUB Status(HUB_Status_HKEY ->PK)`

`HUB Time(HUB_Time_HKEY ->PK) and Satellite (HUB_Time_HKEY(FK),Year,month,day,hour)`

Then structure for transaction LINK would be `TXLNK_SST(TX_LNK_HKEY(PK),HUB_Time_HKEY(FK),HUB_Status_HKEY(FK),Hub_Service_HKEY(FK), Minute_ID, Some_other_fileds_if_any *)` to store transaction at grain minute.

`* -> Since transaction link does not store history so other attributes should be stored in transaction link itself.`

Comment: Thanks narendra, if I understood you right, you suggest to put transaction attributes in link table it self.
I think, I will do it in this way.

Comment: Yes, it's also known as non-historized link and the same mentioned in topic link applications in DV2.0 book.